# Why is my view not getting updated even when @State property has changed?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I decoded the Json response and confirmed its validity,I also am able to print the elements of the array in loadData(). however when I try to access the elements of the response array in my Vstack I get an array out of bounds error. Shouldn't this change the @State welcome var and update my UI?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var welcome = [WelcomeElement]()
    
    
    func loadData() async {
        
        if let url = URL(string: "https://dog-facts-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/resources/dogs?number=5") {
            let (data,_) = try! await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            print(data)
            
            if let welcome = try? (JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)) {
                print(welcome[1])
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    var body: some View {
       
        VStack{
            Text(welcome[1].fact)
            Text(welcome[2].fact)
        }.task {
            await loadData()
        }
    }
    
    
}
// MARK: - WelcomeElement
struct WelcomeElement: Codable {
    let fact: String
}

typealias Welcome = [WelcomeElement]
```

Comment: `loadData` completes *asynchronously* - Do not just try and access the array; Check if the array is empty and how many elements are in it.

Comment: I put an if welcome.count  > 0 check in the Vstack to display the elements but even after a while the UI isn't updating.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add a check in VStack that only display Text if array isn’t empty. This solves the out of bounds crash.

Second, you are never setting the @State var array to the decoded data. You need to set the array variable after decoding.

```
if let welcome = try? (JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)) {
    print(welcome[1])
    self.welcome = welcome
}
```